# Having issues with Crystal Reports not reflecting changes from SQL DB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017

I'm kinda new to creating reports with Crystal Reports on Visual Studio 2017.
I've created a report on VS2017 called PersonnelListingReport.rpt using the setup wizard. Through the wizard I've selected the table for which the report will be based on. Also, I added a filter parameter that will display only the Employees who are active i.e(Active = 1, Inactive = 0). So now in my Main Report Preview window I can see all of the employees with Status = 1. My issue is that when I Add or Delete  an item on my GridView, the change does not reflect on my report. Here's what I have in my Page_Load:

```
Public Class PersonnelListingReportViewer
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim crystalReport As New ReportDocument()

    crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("PersonnelListingReport.rpt"))

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport

End Sub
```

Here's what I have under my aspx for ReportViewer:

```
body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="True" GroupTreeImagesFolderUrl="" Height="1202px" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="" ToolPanelWidth="200px" Width="1104px" />
        <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
            <Report FileName="PersonnelListingReport.rpt">
            </Report>
        </CR:CrystalReportSource>
    </div>
</form>
```

Is there something I am missing in my code? I've tried using Refresh() and Load() as per forum posts with similar issues but to no avail. Ive also read a forum post about creating a Page_Unload then have the report call the Close() and then Dispose() but also to no avail. Ive tried checking the checkbox to Discard Saved Data When Loading Reports but still nothing. I know I'm missing something but not quite sure as this is my first time using Crystal Reports on Visual Studio 2017. Thank guys!

Comment: Had you tried    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind() ;      CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

Comment: Does the Page refresh after Grid events?

Comment: @SreenathGanga I have tried out the two lines of code and it's working, however, the application prompts a Database Login before seeing the updated report. How can I view the updated report without having to put DB credentials in the backend code?

Comment: @JulyOrdinary Yes. I bind the data after the events.

Comment: @Brian.Scalabrine see updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for the advice. I was able to resolve the issue by adding this to my Page_Load:

```
Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
    Dim crtableLogoninfos As New TableLogOnInfos
    Dim crtableLogoninfo As New TableLogOnInfo
    Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo
    Dim CrTables As Tables
    Dim CrTable As Table

    cryRpt.Load(Server.MapPath("PersonnelListingReport.rpt"))

    With crConnectionInfo
        .ServerName = "0.0.0.0"
        .DatabaseName = "TestDB"
        .UserID = "user"
        .Password = "pw"
    End With

    CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables
    For Each CrTable In CrTables
        crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
        crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
        CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)
    Next

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for setting the Logon values for the Crystal report with a function  getreport()  which returns a reportdocument of a  crystal report in a given report location

```
 Module Logonvalues
    Function getpeport(ByVal ReportLocation As String) As ReportDocument
        Dim crconnectioninfo As ConnectionInfo = New ConnectionInfo()
        Dim cryrpt As ReportDocument = New ReportDocument()
        Dim crtablelogoninfos As TableLogOnInfos = New TableLogOnInfos()
        Dim crtablelogoninfo As TableLogOnInfo = New TableLogOnInfo()
        Dim CrTables As Tables
        cryrpt.Load(ReportLocation)
        cryrpt.DataSourceConnections.Clear()
        crconnectioninfo.ServerName = "ur servername"
        crconnectioninfo.DatabaseName = "ur database"
        crconnectioninfo.UserID =  "ur database username"
        crconnectioninfo.Password = "ur database password"
        CrTables = cryrpt.Database.Tables

        For Each CrTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In CrTables
            crtablelogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
            crtablelogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crconnectioninfo
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtablelogoninfo)
        Next

        Return cryrpt
    End Function
End Module
```

Finally we will  call the logon value from the form consisting of the crystal reportviewer

```
Public Sub loadreport()
    Crvt_ApplicationReport.ReportSource = Logonvalues.getpeport("yourlocation")
    Crvt_ApplicationReport.SelectionFormula = "yourformula if any"
    Crvt_ApplicationReport.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```